# "%matplotlib inline" in iPython Notebook doesnt change back to separate window when removed and re-run

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, ipython

I'm hoping someone can help me out.

I often find myself wanting to print figures in separate windows in iPython Notebook and within my browser when writing code and analysing figures, but keep running into a problem.

I noticed that if I add "%matplotlib inline" to my code somewhere to print the plots in the browser, but then remove it, the code continues to print the plot in the browser and not open in a new window. The only way around this I find is to just close the notebook and reopen it entirely from the command line.

Does anyone know of a simple "%" argument to place in the code that will reset it so that it prints plots to separate windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just removing `%matplotlib inline` will not remove the effect the command had - which is in effect until the kernel is restarted (through notebook's menu) or until another gui is explicitly called (like `%matplotlib qt` or another one depending on your environment). See more in the [docs](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/magics.html?highlight=backends#magic-matplotlib).